# Tmux подключение к сессии

Tags: сессия, putty, tmux

Работаю с **PuTTY** подключен к хостингу на нем установлен **Tmux** и я запустил своего бота

```
node server.js
```

Потом отключился `Ctrl+B,D` и закрыл консоль бот работал теперь мне нужно сделать обновление и **как мне выключить сессию? я не могу подключиться к ней.**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: вы создаёте новую tmux-сессию, и из неё пытаетесь подключиться к старой. просто не создавайте новую tmux-сессию, а подключайтесь к старой.

Comment: а как??????????????

Comment: как вы подключаетесь к серверу?

Comment: К хостингу по айпи и пишу пароль логин потом пишу tmux

Comment: вот и не пишите «потом tmux», а пишите например, `tmux a -t 0`

Comment: ААААААААААААААААААААААААААА сработало большое спасибо большое просто большое

Answer (score 1):

Вы уже в tmux'е (потому и ругается).
Используйте быстрые клавиши или команды:

1. Ctrl + b s и затем выбрать нужную сессию стрелками вверх/вниз и Enter.
2. Ctrl + b : `switch -t 0` -- ввод команды в командном режиме внутри tmux.
3. Прямо в самой сессии надо использовать switch, а не attach: `tmux switch -t 0`(это скорее всего то что надо).